# Firefox/Safari setting height as [specified height - padding - border] for input[type=button]

Tags: html, css, height, padding

When I use the following CSS:

```
input[type=button] {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 15px;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 7px;
}
```

with this HTML:

```
<input type="button" value="Foo" />
```

I expect to see this, so the total height becomes `36px`:

```
1px  border
7px  padding
20px content (with 15px text)
7px  padding
1px  border
```

But instead both Firefox 3.6 and Safari 4 show this: (Haven't tested in other browsers)

[Screenshot http://labs.spiqr.nl/upload/files/1223ef9cbae3ab6e43bd1f9215ebedb157ac7b22.png](http://labs.spiqr.nl/upload/files/1223ef9cbae3ab6e43bd1f9215ebedb157ac7b22.png)

```
1px border
7px padding
4px content (with 15px text) => height - 2 * border - 2 * padding
7px padding
1px border
```

Does anyone have any idea why this happens?

(Even if it's expected behavior, what's the logic behind it?)

Comment: Image link broken (use imgur!)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Form elements have traditionally had a `width`/`height` that includes their padding/border, because they were originally implemented by browsers as OS-native UI widgets, where CSS had no influence over the decorations.

To reproduce this behaviour, Firefox and others render some form fields (select, button/input-type-button) with the CSS3 [box-sizing](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-ui/#box-sizing) style set to `border-box`, so that the `width` property reflects the entire rendered area width including the border and padding.

You can disable this behaviour with:

```
select, button {
    box-sizing: content-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

(or, which is more common for liquid form layouts where you want to use ‘100%’ width, you can set the others to `border-box`.)

The -browser prefixed versions have to be there to catch browsers that implemented this before the standardisation process got so far. This will be ineffective on IE6-7, though.

Answer (score 1):

A few things you can try:

- Set the [**doctype**](http://ejohn.org/blog/html5-doctype/) of the document (`<!DOCTYPE html>`)
- Set the input to be `display:block` or `display: inline-block`
- Use a [**reset stylesheet**](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/).

Comment: Changing the DOCTYPE from HTML4 Transitional to HTML5 worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

It makes sense because the height of the element is naturally more than what you set it to. input elements are assigned a height which, in this case, should be enough to contain the text of your element but you set it to a smaller amount. To show this, remove your height setting.

Comment: Other elements work like I said: The total height is `border-top + padding-top + height + padding-bottom + border-bottom`.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working removing the padding of the input button and setting a height around 20. then adjusting the height, padding of the anchor element.
I Also set the line-height, font-size and the font-family.

worked on FF,IE,safari and chrome :D